# Stream video using FFmpeg with minimum writes reads to disk

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, streaming, live

We are streaming a video using a 30 instances of docker containers hosted on Azure each instance running FFmpeg. The problem is that Azure limits the reads/writes that a container can do. Is there a way to modify the command to reduce the reads/writes needed to stream?

```
ffmpeg -re -i file.mp4 -c copy -f flv rtmps://streamingSite.com/live/x4t
```

Comment: No, that command will read the file only once, and never write anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly the limitation is; let assume you don't want using disk I/O; how about ramdisk? [The link](https://linuxhint.com/ramdisk_ubuntu_1804/) tells you how

Comment: Awesome, thanks.